# Azure AD multi-tenant app unpredictable behaviour?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, activedirectorymembership

I am trying to build a scalable multi-tenant b2b SAAS in Azure AD using Angular in the front end and node + Azure MS SQL sharded db design.

I've spend a week going through the MS documentation and examples (tailspin, survey apps) and have started testing the multi-tenant behaviour in an angular7 app that has nothing other than authentication with [adal-angular4](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4#readme) on it which I've used for ~5 other projects that are currently in production.

So far, I can't for the life of me figure out the reason behind this unpredictable behaviour. I have 3 tenants: A - B - C

A is the developer tenant + my admin account, B is another company's tenant + my normal user account and C is a AD Free tier tenant with my personal account.

I have done nothing else to my app in Azure AD on the developer AD other than switch that multi-tenant setting to on and changing Oauth2implicitflow to true.

- If I login with Tenant A into the app, all is good, in the console I
  can see tenant A's GUID under TID.
- If I login with Tenant B - it asks for permissions the first time and then lets me in (why??).
- If I login with Tenant C 'work' account it throws no errors, does not ask for permission, returns back to the page without actually being logged in and with nothing on the console.
- If I login with Tenant C 'personal' account it tells me the tenant live.com is not provisioned for the app.

My questions are:

1. Why did it even let Tenant B to log into the app? They were definitely not provisioned to be able to access it and on the console the tid is clearly of the second tenant meaning (I think) that the account is NOT a guest on tenant A to be able to login.
2. I have no idea why the tenant C throws no error on the Azure side but instead just returns back to the page without actually being logged in.
3. Is there any documentation that I'm missing on which tenants can sign up into the app? I have looked at [Tenant sign-up and onboarding article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/signup) but it doesn't really address the issue.

Based on the documentation that I have read, the behaviour of Tenant B and C trying to log into the app makes no sense.

Comment: For your first question, when the first user consents to permissions (and is able to do so), a service principal for the app is created in their tenant and they are logged in.

Comment: @juunas so that means that anyone with an account could technically sign up to my app? Is there a piece of documentation that I'm missing on how to limit this behaviour? I obviously only want the app to be used by 'allowed' tenants.

The 'provisioning' on the app in AD is set to 'manual' with no other option currently.

Comment: At the moment, no. Your app back-end needs to check tenant ids of users to see they are one of the valid ones. Your front-end can of course check as well, though it cannot replace the back-end checks.

Comment: Multi-tenant app = any Azure AD tenant can use this app

Comment: @juunas --- Of course, I'm going to manage the multi-tenancy of the data in the back-end and even if that user would be able to 'sign in' they wouldn't be able to actually  "use" the app or get any data from the database.

I was just thinking if it is the desired behaviour for the front-end to allow anyone to authenticate at all and then let the developer manage the data-flow.

And if not, what part am I missing?

Comment: The problem is, you can specify a single tenant that the user should use to authenticate (as a suggestion) when sending the user to login, but in case you don't know, you cannot specify a set of tenants.

Comment: @juunas so then the designed strategy would be that I use adal as an authentication/authorization/roles/permission/etc. solution but once the user is logged in it's completely up to the app and AD is just agnostic to the app at that point? should I just let the user in and then design the mechanism that just tells the user 'your organisation has not signed up to this app?' and offer them some options or whatever I want? Is that the right/designed way of approaching it?

Comment: That's pretty much the way people do it. Just make sure you don't accidentally trigger your framework's authentication code again like I did. Leads to a redirect loop :D

Comment: @juunas thank you for the insight -- with this knowledge I can deduce what was an anomaly and what is the desired behaviour. I will continue to look into the behaviour of Tenant C as an error with Tenant C instead of thinking that Tenant B is the anomaly. I'd be happy to mark your answer as the right solution if you post it as an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did it even let Tenant B to log into the app? They were definitely not provisioned to be able to access it and on the console the tid is clearly of the second tenant meaning (I think) that the account is NOT a guest on tenant A to be able to login.

When the first user consents to permissions (and is able to do so), a service principal for the app is created in their tenant and they are logged in.
This is how multi-tenant apps are designed to work.
This means any tenant can login to your app.

Your app back-end needs to check tenant ids of users to see they are one of the valid ones. Your front-end can of course check as well, though it cannot replace the back-end checks.